# CSS, jQuery - delay on losing focus with min-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, focus, delay

I want to create a delay upon losing focus of a textarea. Currently I have:

```
<textarea name="description"></textarea>
```

My CSS reads

```
.my-form textarea {
 height: 35px;
}

.my-form textarea:focus {
 min-height: 100px;
}
```

There is a radio button toggle right beneath this. It gets pushed down because of the extra pixels added on focus, but when trying to click on a button it loses its focus, the height goes back to the original, and you miss the click.

Is there a way to create a delay when losing focus for say 100 ms, just enough to register the click on the buttons?

Comment: Can you please update the question with HTML, it would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible with css... with javacript it is possible

Comment: Eh? Why? This is all the HTML I have and that is needed? And I did say jQuery - plain Javascript is always okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using CSS**

```
  .my-form textarea {
        height: 35px;
        transition: height 0.3s ease 1s;
    }

    .my-form textarea:focus {
        min-height: 100px;
    }
```

**Using JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.my-form textarea').focusin(function () {
                $(this).css('height', '100px');
            });

            $('.my-form textarea').focusout(function () {
                setTimeout(function () { $('.my-form textarea').css('height', '35px'); }, 500);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try css3 transition

```
.my-form textarea {
    height: 35px;
    transition: width ease 0.3s 0.5s;
}

.my-form textarea:focus {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/689gv/1/